# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of a bivariat uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, density-function, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I have to find the size and position of a window given four light points. The light points are i.i.d. from a uniform distribution with the parameter $\theta := (x_{min},x_{max},y_{min},y_{max})$. Each point is $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,2)$.

First I need to complete the pdf, $f_\theta (x,y)$, by finding the value c, through the parameters given. 
[image: The pdf]

I though this was quite easy, as I just used $\frac{1}{\Delta x \cdot \Delta y}=\frac{1}{(x_{max}-x_{min})\cdot (y_{max}-y_{min})}$

Next I have two values for $\theta$ that I need to calculate the likelihood for. $\theta_1 = (-1,4,-1,3)$ and $\theta_2 = (-2,5,-3,6)$. So we can calculate the value c for both of them: $c_1=\frac{1}{20}$, $c_2=\frac{1}{63}$. Here comes my first real question. Since it is a uniform distribution is it okay to just say:
$$\mathcal{L}_{\theta_1} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(4-(-1))\cdot(3-(-1))}=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{20}= \frac{1}{160,000}, \quad n=4$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{\theta_2} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(5-(-2))\cdot(6-(-3))}= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{63}= \frac{1}{15,752,961}, \quad n=4$$ 
Is this acceptable?

After that I need to calculate the $MLE\; \hat{\theta}^{ML}=(\hat{x}_{min},\hat{x}_{max},\hat{y}_{min},\hat{y}_{max})$. I am guessing the result would be a vector of the differentiated function for $x_{min}$ for $x_{max}$ for $y_{min}$ for $y_{max}$ equal to $0$? I'm guessing I should use the natural logaritmetic of the function as it is easier, but I'm stuck at what they expect me to do. If I differentiate $\prod_{i=1}^n ln(\frac{1}{(x_{max}-x_{min})\cdot (y_{max}-y_{min})})$ with respect to $x_{max}$ I get $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_{min}-x_{max}}$. I'll still have two variables. What am I missing? I think, I might have to work with

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in your notation. You introduce $\theta$ as a quadruple of numbers, but in the displayed equations in the middle of the post they appear to be scalars. Please clarify. (Also note that the verb corresponding to "derivative" is "differentiate", not "derive".)

Comment: You are right. It is the likelihood of $\theta$. I think, I maybe should use vector notation. Unfortunately I am not entirely sure how the maximum likelihood estimation should be calculated, as there are no dependencies in this joint density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t get the maximum likelihood estimate through differentiation in this case because it’s on the boundary. The density is higher the smaller the window is, so the window with maximal density (and hence likelihood) is the smallest one compatible with the observations. This is $\theta=(0,2,0,2)$.

Your likelihood calculation is correct, but you don’t mention the essential point that the four observations lie in both of these windows and that otherwise their likelihood would be $0$.

It’s not entirely clear what you mean by “find the pdf, $c$”. What you later calculate as $c$ is just the constant normalization factor in the density; the probability density function is the product of this constant factor with the indicator function of the window.

Comment: I absolutely agree with the observation. Unfortunately, the assignment is rather specific. It says, I need to "compute the ML $\hat{\theta}^{ML}$".  About the "find the pdf". I've worded it wrong. I should complete the pdf by finding c.

Comment: @NBuch: I'm not sure what you're saying. Are you saying that what I did isn't a "computation" and hence doesn't satisfy the assignment? In my view, that would be a rather narrow view of the scope of "computation"; and I don't see how the maximum likelihood value of $\theta$ could be "computed" under that narrow interpretation. I'd say I computed it.